# Вопрос с message_handler telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть два таких метода

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda mes: str(mes.text).isdigit())
     async def create_requests(message: types.Message):
```

Один обрабатывает сумму пополнения платежа, а другой вычисляет проценты с введеного числа. В общем оба хендлера принимают число. Есть ли способ определять что именно сейчас делает пользователь пополняет или расчитывает? Я сделал так

```
list_pay = []       
list_calc = []
```

Создал два списка. И когда пользователь переходит в раздел, например, пополнение добавляю его в `list_pay`

```
if callback.from_user.id not in list_pay:
    list_pay.append(callback.from_user.id)
```

И так отслеживаю его, а после оплаты удаляю из `list_pay`. Также сделал и для `list_calc`.

Можно ли как-то иначе реализовать это без `костылей`

Comment: Почти ничего не понял. Добавьте код.

Comment: Добавил код, и переделал вопрос

Comment: Вы что-то знаете просто fsm  и стейты в айограме? Думаю вам стоит узнать

Comment: немного знаю, но разве там можно создать машину состояний для каждого пользователя?

Comment: т.е. можно ли для каждого пользователя создавать свой fsm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых. В

```
lambda mes: str(mes.text).isdigit()
```

Можно спокойно убрать `str(mes.text)`. И сделать так. `text` точно будет строкой.

```
lambda msg: msg.text.isdigit()
```

Насчет FSM. Можно сделать так.

```
# некий хендлер до ввода числа
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer("Введите число...")
    # дальше запускаем стейт
    await InputData.input_calc.set()
    

# в филтре указываем нужный стейт при котором сработает хендлер
@dp.message_handler(state=InputData.input_pay)
async def get_int(msg: types.Message):
    # я бы проверку на число делал внутри хендлера, 
    # так можно было бы сразу обработать неправильный ввод 
    if msg.text.isdigit():
        await msg.answer("1")
    else:
        await msg.answer("Введите число")
```

Comment: ок, а что если несколько людей сразу юзают бота, там ошибок со стейтами не будет?

Comment: @Tura у каждого чата и юзера свой стейт

Comment: понял, спасибо)